# 6th degree equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

The number of real roots of 
$$
\frac{3}{x-3}+\frac{5}{x-5}+\frac{17}{x-17}+\frac{19}{x-19} = x^2 -11x -4
$$
How to solve without actually finding the roots or is it the only way?
I know that if the equation changes it's sign between two no.s it will have at least one root contained in them.

Comment: @MorganRodgers It becomes a sixth degree equation after cross multiplying.

Comment: This is a rational function, so if there is a sign change somewhere, it could also be due to a pole (vertical asymptote). There is a solution that you can find by just guessing.

Comment: What you say isn't quite true.  When $x$ is just a little less than $3,$ then first term is very large in absolute value, but negative.  When $x$ is just a little bigger than $3$ the first time is very large and positive.  There is no root between these two values, because the function isn't defined at $x=3$.

Comment: Wouldn't $3$,$5$,$17$,$19$ be roots?

Comment: There are $6$ real roots.  $x=0$, a root between $0$ and $3$, a root between $3$ and $5$, a root between $5$ ad $17$, a root between $17$ and $19$, and finally a root larger than $19$.

Comment: @FareedAF No, the left hand side isn't defined at those values.

Comment: Attempt a plot. Consider the values: $x=0, 2.807, 4.847, 11, 17.153, 19.133$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use descartes rule of sign after you make the expression in the general form of a polynomial.
see:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs.